# Mootools in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mootools

For my client side development I use MooTools primarily, I have also just recently started learning rails. What is the best method of using Mootools in rails pages? Just adding my code inline like I would any other server side language? Or is there a better and cleaner way to do things?

Basically I'm asking the most conventional way of integrating Mootools into my rails application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? Starting from Rails 3, the preferred way is to use unobstrusive javascript and there is a [driver for Mootools](http://github.com/kevinvaldek/mootools-ujs) to do that.

Comment: I am currently on Rails 2.3.5, should I upgrade. Like I said I'm new to the community and don't have a feel for the trends yet.

Comment: If you are still new to Rails, I would suggest getting your hands ready for Rails 3 since you've got nothing to lose and not maintaining legacy project.